# How to trigger remote windows PC through the proxy by the command

Tags: triggers, proxy, command

I want to trigger remote the PC through proxy by the command.

I try to used the command is
`wmic /USER:user_name /PASSWORD:password /NODE:"ip_address" process call create "cmd /c notepad.exe"`

But it not work.

So is have any the command to trigger remote PC through the proxy?